# Multiple Choice and Hidden Reports

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I have specified the Values in the Which Report Parameter

```
Label                                    Value 
Occupancy                                Occupancy 
Pitch Nights Sold                        PitchNightsSold 
Capacity                                 Capacity 
Pitch Nights Sold And Capacity           PitchNightsSoldAndCapacity 
Pitch Nights Sold And Occupancy          PitchNightsSoldAndOccupancy 
Pitch Nights Sold Capacity And Occupancy PitchNightsSoldCapacityAndOccupancy
```

Main Dataset:

```
SELECT 

OccupancyDetail.CalendarYear, 
OccupancyDetail.CalendarMonth, 
SUM(OccupancyDetail.No_of_Nights) AS No_of_Nights, 
SUM(OccupancyDetail.Capacity) AS Capacity

FROM            
OccupancyDetail INNER JOIN
    Site ON OccupancyDetail.Site_Skey = Site.Site_Skey

WHERE  (OccupancyDetail.ReferenceDate = convert(Date,getdate()))
AND CASE WHEN @Time = 'YEAR' THEN CAST(CalendarYear as varchar(4)) else CalendarMonth + ' ' + CAST(CalendarYear as varchar(4)) end in (@Dates)

AND ((@ReportingLevel = 'BDM' AND Site.BDM in(@BDM_Region_Site))
    OR (@ReportingLevel = 'Region' AND Site.Region in (@BDM_Region_Site))
    OR (@ReportingLevel = 'SiteName' AND Site.SiteName in (@BDM_Region_Site)))

GROUP BY OccupancyDetail.ReferenceDate,OccupancyDetail.CalendarYear, OccupancyDetail.CalendarMonth
```

Time Dataset:

```
select 
DateChoice 

FROM
(
select distinct 
CalendarYear, 
1 as MonthNumber,
CAST(CalendarYear as varchar(4)) as DateChoice 
from Time
where @Time = 'YEAR'


union all

select Distinct 
CalendarYear, 
MonthNumber,
CalendarMonth + ' ' + CAST(CalendarYear as varchar(4)) as DateChoice 
from Time 
where @Time = 'MONTH'
) as QRYDATA

ORDER BY CalendarYear,MonthNumber
```

Site Dataset:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BDM AS SiteInfo FROM Site
WHERE @ReportingLevel = 'BDM'


UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT Region  FROM Site
WHERE @ReportingLevel = 'Region'


UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT SiteName  FROM Site
WHERE @ReportingLevel = 'SiteName'
```

On Report Builder 3.0 I have created 6 reports that are hidden unless it is selected in a parameter:

Report Code Visibility string:

```
=iif(Parameters!WhichReport.Value(0) = "Occupancy", False, True)
```

But what I want to do is make the Parameter a multiple select parameter so someone can choose two charts instead of 1 or choose all 6 etc but whatever selection is made all other reports need to stay hidden. Can this be done and if so how?

Thanks

Wayne

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `Hidden` expression to achieve this:

Turn all the selected reports into a string using `Join`, then check if the relevant report name is in the string, something like:

```
=IIf(
  InStr(Join(Parameters!WhichReport.Value, ","), "Occupancy Report") > 0
  , False
  , True
)
```

Or, for a different item:

```
=IIf(
  InStr(Join(Parameters!WhichReport.Value, ","), "Capacity Report") > 0
  , False
  , True
)
```

**Edit after comment:**

I guess you're getting mismatches as values like `PitchNightsSold` and `PitchNightsSoldAndCapacity` will confuse the expression as written.

I would use a Dataset similar to the following to control item visibility:

```
Label                                      Value
-----                                      -----
Occupancy                                  Chart1
Pitch Nights Sold                          Chart2
Capacity                                   Chart3
Pitch Nights Sold And Capacity             Chart4
Pitch Nights Sold And Occupancy            Chart5
Pitch Nights Sold Capacity And Occupancy   Chart6
```

Then expressions like:

```
=IIf(
  InStr(Join(Parameters!WhichReport.Value, ","), "Chart1") > 0
  , False
  , True
)
```

Will only ever apply to one item.

Since these are your own internal constant values, you can call them whatever you want; just make them distinct and unambiguous. The label will remain unchanged so users will be unaffected when running the report.

**Edit after comment:**

In a comment @glh offers a good solution to similar `Value` values:

> ...if you wrap you join in commas and search for them this will remove
>   the partial finds.

So something like:

```
=IIf(
  InStr("," + Join(Parameters!WhichReport.Value, ",") + ",", ",PitchNightsSold,") > 0
  , False
  , True
)
```

Would work very well, too; credit to him for the suggestion.

Comment: Hi Ian, Thanks for the reply, your solution sort of works but it fails on my last 3 reports and I think its all to do with the name of the reports Report 1 - Occupancy Report 2 - Pitch Nights Sold Report 3 - Capacity Report 4 - Pitch Nights Sold and Capacity Report 5 - Pitch Nights Sold and Occupancy Report 6 - Pitch Nights Sold, Capacity and Occupancy Report

So when I use your solution and run Report 4 I get the Pitch Nights Sold Report and the Capacity Report and then the Combo report and all I want to see is the combo report.

Comment: Did you change the name for each report item? You can't just use the same piece of code each time, you have to update it for your own purposes.

Comment: Hi Ian, I updated it with the name of each report when I went in to change that reports Visibility.

=IIf(
  InStr(Join(Parameters!WhichReport.Value, ","), "PitchNightsSoldAndCapacity") > 0
  , False
  , True
)

Comment: Can you please add your full Dataset details to the question?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer, I meant the details used to populate the WhichReport parameter, and maybe some examples of the expressions you're using. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: Hi Ian, I have specified the Values in the Which Report Parameter

Label                                        Value
Occupancy                                    Occupancy
Pitch Nights Sold                            PitchNightsSold
Capacity                                     Capacity
Pitch Nights Sold And Capacity            PitchNightsSoldAndCapacity
Pitch Nights Sold And Occupancy          PitchNightsSoldAndOccupancy
Pitch Nights Sold Capacity And Occupancy PitchNightsSoldCapacityAndOccupancy

Comment: @IanPreston, if you wrap you `join` in commas and search for them this will remove the partial finds. `InStr("," + Join(Parameters!WhichReport.Value, ",") + ",", ",PitchNightsSold,")`

Comment: @glh that would definitely work, too. Nice one, very cool! I suppose it makes the expression slightly more complex, so it's really whatever makes the best sense to whomever's implementing; up to the OP which route to choose.